# generate dynamic html content in a file using pl/sql - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to generate a HTML file using pl/sql stored procedure. I can do this writing the code statically and then use `utl_file`, but also i need to show some tables that are generated from a query (here is the dynamic part). I found in google that [owa_util](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10802/w_util.htm) can do this using `TABLEPRINT` function, but i did not found how to store the result in a varchar2 variable, looks like this is not what i need.

Is there any way to do this in oracle? 
For example:

Input:

```
select 'Pepe' nombre, 25 edad from dual;
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Nombre</td>
<td>Edad</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pepe</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_format_output_html_xml.htm

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for reply, but what i need is to generate html code using tags `<table><tr><td>`, dbms_xmlgen generates tables in xml form using `<rowset>` and `<row>`

Comment: So, replace those strings afterwards or use an xslt transform

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what application you have access to run these queries. Oracle's SQL Developer has built in HTML export/reporting

you could try using spool and sqlplus.

example:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_html_sql_plus.htm

documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch8.htm

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is sqlpus, i'm using toad, then i need to do this in plsql only.